# How to get the header view of a grouped table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I want to get all the views of a grouped table view to change the label color and to set the background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, it's not possible to get the header view of a table view section. But you can implement the delegate `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` to recreate the header view and the label. The following code will give you the same header view and the exact label.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString *sectionTitle = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];

    if (sectionTitle == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create label with section title
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 5.5f, 300.0f, 30.0f)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.5];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
    label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    label.text = sectionTitle;

    // Create header view and add label as a subview
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0f)];
    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [view addSubview:label];

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's great you figured out your solution.

A couple of suggestions:

1. Don't hardcode the CGRect for the width of your frame, but rather use `self.view.size.width` for the width (e.g. in case you're in landscape orientation or if Apple ever introduces an iPhone with a different screen size);
2. You probably want to use `autoresizingMask` for both the label and the view that holds the label, so that they'll resize as the screen orientation changes, or make sure you invoke `[self.tableview reloadData]` on orientation changes; and
3. This is obviously a single line label ... if that works for you great, otherwise you'd want to use `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode` to determine the height, both for creating the label/view as well as responding to `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add the textColor:

```
 label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.265 green:0.294 blue:0.367 alpha:1.000];
```